# SQL Form submit result

Tags: php, sql, forms

I want to display a message something like: "Congrats! you have been registered".
But the message appears on the top left corner of the page. I want to display it in the same page below the "Submit Button".
Here's my code:

```
if($result)
    {
        //send the email

        $to = "xyz@abc.com";
        $subject = "New order for Weaving Hope";

        //headers and subject
        $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n";

        $body = "New contact<br />";
        $body .= "Name: ".$name."<br />";
        $body .= "Email: ".$email."<br />";
        $body .= "Contact No.: ".$contact."<br />";
        $body .= "Item Id: ".$itemid."<br />";
        $body .= "Quantity: ".$itemquantity."<br />";
        $body .= "Comment: ".$comment."<br />";
        $body .= "IP: ".$ip."<br />";

        mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

        //ok message

        echo "Congrats!";
    }
```

Comment: You'd need AJAX to do the form submission then.

Comment: Can't I do it without ajax??I don't know ajax<except the name>.
Can you help me out here please?

Answer (score 0):

This page should be easy to follow, it tells you exactly what to do.
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this without AJAX, then you need to process the form data in the same PHP page that sends the form to the browser, and set a flag to determine whether or not the data submission was successful.

For example:

```
<?php // Call this page register.php

$success = false;
if( $result)
{
    // .. Your code from above
    $success = true;
}

?>
<form action="register.php" method="post">
    <!-- Output the form for submission here -->
    <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" />
    <?php if( $success): ?>
        <span>Congrats, you are registered!</span>
    <?php endif; ?>
</form>
```

Comment: Won't that reload the page and remove all of the inputs?

Comment: Thanks @nickb. 
Jared: It doesn't matter if it reloads the page and removes all the inputs. I just wanted to display a message. Thanks anyways.